# How to show this function in php

Tags: php, function

What I need to know it how to display this `function`. This `function` is made in a different file and I want to show it in an other one. but I am not sure if this code is working the way I need it to but I am not sure how to display this `function` the correct way.

[image]

```
function tijd_reactie() {

        $getTimestamp = $this->database->query("SELECT id, create_time FROM reacties WHERE id=1"); 
        $creat_time = $this->database->single();
        $cur_time   = time();
        $make_time = mktime($create_time['create_time']);
        $time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $make_time;
        $seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
        $minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
        $hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
        $days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
        $weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
        $months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
        $years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );

        // Seconds
        if($seconds <= 60){
            return "just now";
        }
        //Minutes
        else if($minutes <=60){
            if($minutes==1){
                return "one minute ago";
            }
            else{
                return "$minutes minutes ago";
            }
        }
        //Hours
        else if($hours <=24){
            if($hours==1){
                return "an hour ago";
            }else{
                return "$hours hrs ago";
            }
        }
        //Days
        else if($days <= 7){
            if($days==1){
                return "yesterday";
            }else{
                return "$days days ago";
            }
        }
        //Weeks
        else if($weeks <= 4.3){
            if($weeks==1){
                return "a week ago";
            }else{
                return "$weeks weeks ago";
            }
        }
        //Months
        else if($months <=12){
            if($months==1){
                return "a month ago";
            }else{
                return "$months months ago";
            }
        }
        //Years
        else{
            if($years==1){
                return "one year ago";
            }else{
                return "$years years ago";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define "show"  .

Comment: You need to learn programming terminology because there is no such thing as "showing" a function.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: `require` file where the function is in a file you want to display and call it like `echo tijd_reactie();`.

Comment: *"How to show this function in php"* - Call it?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Like this? _Here function function. Come to daddy. Come on boy_ :)

Comment: you can use include() or require() function if you want to use code of another file in a file, and can call normally as a function is called. function_name();

Comment: @RiggsFolly Perfect.

Comment: @Rahul I have that but when I call the function by name it doesnt displat anything

Comment: @GytisTenovimas  I have that but when I call the function by name it doesnt displat anything

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's the one way to do :-D

Comment: @blahetpo Then perhaps there is an error in your function but you have turned off error displaying.

Comment: No I have error displaying on @GytisTenovimas

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand is you want to call this function from another file.

I see from the comments that most are not helpful at all.
(From someone who used google to learn php from no programming background I find the comments rude.)

You should be able to `include('/path/to/the/file/that/includes/the/function.php');`

then you can call the function from then file (under the include)
tijd_reactie();

Depending on how you use this function you will then need to do something with what it returns.

The most simplest way to use it would be to echo it out to the page:
`echo tijd_reactie();`

So your finished file might look something like this:

```
<?php
include('/path/to/file.php');
echo tijd_reactie();
```